# Array is ignoring last index for some number of array length

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void display(int[] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
        }
        System.out.printf("\n");
    }

    // this one is the problematic one.
    public static int min(int[] arr, int start, int end) {
        int middle = start + (end - start)/2;

        if (start >= middle) {
            return arr[start];
        }

        int min_1 = min(arr, start, middle);
        int min_3 = (min_1 <= arr[middle])? min_1 : arr[middle];
        int min_2 = min(arr, middle+1, end);

        return (min_3 <= min_2)? min_3 : min_2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int len;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.printf("Enter the length of array: ");
        len = in.nextInt();

        int[] arr = new int[len];

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            arr[i] = (int)(10*Math.random()+1);
        }
        arr[len-1] = 0;

        display(arr);
        System.out.printf("%d is the min", min(arr, 0, arr.length-1));

    }
}
```

Problem is: the method min() works for the other places of minimum number (which is "0" in this example) for example if I put "0" in the 3rd place (by changing arr[len-1] = 0 part), method returns me 0. If I change the input length "len" to 3,7,13 or 14 it returns me 0, which is correct however for other lengths such as 4,5,8,9, it returns the second minimum number. And what is even more interesting is that if I make the end point "arr.length" instead of "arr.length-1", it won't give an error for some lengths (for instance for len = 6, it gives ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException), moreover it works correctly and returns 0 in the situations where it doesn't give an error. I really don't understand what is the exact problem (Note: I must find the min number recursively and by finding the min of first half and second half and comparing them, so other solutions will not help me :/).

Comment: Your code looks like `end` is exclusive, so why do you use `bList.min(0,nums.size()-1)` instead of `bList.min(0,nums.size())`?

Comment: I tried end+1 as well but the results were the same and if it was the problem, then it wouldn't give me correct input for size of numbers 3,7,13 and so on. Also, when I write it as you say, it gives an IndexOutOfBoundsException when I add 6 numbers.

Comment: Then you algorith might has issues with even and odd amounts of numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's consider an execution passing 4, and let's say it generates arr = [6, 10, 2, 0]

The first invocation of min() will be passed 0, 3 as start,end. middle will be 0 + (3 - 0) / 2 = 1

so, you'll call

```
min_1 = min(arr, 0, 1)
```

in this execution min will have middle = 0 + (1 - 0) / 2 = 0, end hence it will return arr[0], i.e. 6.

We're back in the outer min(), where min_3 is computed as the min between (6 and 10, i.e. 6. Then we compute min_2 = min(arr, 2, 3)

we're now in this inner execution of min. Here middle = 2 + (3 - 2) / 2 = 2. As middle == start, we return arr[2], i.e. 2.

We're back in the outer min, where we finally compute the min between min_3 and min_1, which is 2, and return it. Note that we never processed arr[3]

The problem here is your condition to stop the recursion. The idea here is that you want to stop recursion when you've degenerated to a case where you're looking at an interva of size 1. The condition for that should not be start >= middle, but rather start >= end.

Comment: It works and you explained it really well, thank you :) And btw can someone tell me the time complexity of this code?